# How to move a column to the left without removing data in the cell to the left?

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Screenshot]

Image 1 is how I got it now, image 2 is how I would like it to be. Can anybody explain to me how?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Stein. Please note that you need to include the necessary details in the question, not in an externally linked image. [Otherwise your question might get put on hold.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911893/excel-vba-help-me-in-this) Also, if you have written any code you'd like us to debug, please post it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Go To Special, [Select Blanks](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1065-excel-select-empty-cells.html), and delete the blank sells. In VBA it would be something like:

```
Cells.UnMerge
Range("A:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlShiftToLeft
```

Comment: Looking at the picture it seems to me that the cells in question are merged cells. So, to accomplish the desired result the OP will probably have to (1) unmerge the cells, (2) move the content of the merged cells one column to the right `.OffSet(0, 1)`, and then (3) he can delete the entire column `A`. Note: I tried your solution and the merged cells got deleted. But maybe my setup was incorrect?!

Comment: @Ralph good point, but I can't test it either way. To me it seems like deleting the blank cells in the first 2 columns should be enough and I didn't think the merged cells would be affected. So, the merged non-blank cells are deleted too?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Longer answer: I was not sure how Excel would treate the merged cells. Hence I tested it. Yet, I figured that Excel treats merged cells the following way. A merged cell along 3 cells consists (essentially) of 1 non-empty cell and 2 empty cells. By deleting the 2 empty cells the first non-empty cell gets also deleted because it is merged with the others.

Comment: @Ralph good to know. I was expecting and error when attempting to delete part of merged cell, but sounds like it just deletes the `.MergeArea`